# Binding to dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery, dynamic, binding

All articles I read about jQuery not working on dynamically added DOM elements refer to on and click..etc..

and I'm not clear how my scenario plays into this..

I have an timepicker field on my stage (at page load)..

```
<input class="form-control timepicker timepicker-with-dropdown text-center" id="startTime1" name="startTime1" placeholder="Start Time 1">
```

class of timepicker.

I have this code from the timepicker documentation:

```
//Timepicker (added here for dynamically added elements)
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
    interval: 30,
    minTime: '0',
    maxTime: '11:30p',
    defaultTime: '0',
    startTime: '',
    dynamic: true,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: true
});
$('.timepicker').val("");
```

I have a button that dynamically adds more of these 'timepicker' (input fields)

as you know.. these dynamically added fields do NOT respond/work as timepickers.. since the jQuery isnt applied (because of them being dynamically added to the stage)..

The timepicker has its own css and js files...  (which I assusme just finds the class and adds/does what it needs to)

What I did to get it working was just add the:

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker({......
```

snippet to the:

```
$(add_button).click(function(event){.....
```

that adds the dynamic elements...

But that seems a bit redundant?  (since I have the same exact blocks now.. one inside my $(add_button).click(function(event){..  and one outside of it.. for the default ones on stage during page load.

Is there a better or more efficient way that I should be doing this?

Comment: Extract logic to single function.  Reuse function.  Go get coffee.

Comment: You generally can't attach a plugin like the timepicker to an element that doesn't exist, unless the plugin is specifically written to work that way. You solved the issue the correct way, and can close your question.

Comment: Given that the timepicker widget isn't applied, then we know these dynamically added fields *can't possibly* work as timepickers. Absolutely no surprises. 

So apply the widget after adding the fields.

Comment: @adeneo 
Thanks!

@ Roamer-1888 
Are you suggesting an alternate approach? Or saying what I posted is correct?